# DataFrame.groupby.rank producing wrong results?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Heres two tables -

```
Employees
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| id | name  | salary | departmentId |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
| 1  | Joe   | 70000  | 1            |
| 2  | Jim   | 90000  | 1            |
| 3  | Henry | 80000  | 2            |
| 4  | Sam   | 60000  | 2            |
| 5  | Max   | 90000  | 1            |
+----+-------+--------+--------------+
```

```
Department table:
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | IT    |
| 2  | Sales |
+----+-------+
```

```
Required Output

Output: 
+------------+----------+--------+
| Department | Employee | Salary |
+------------+----------+--------+
| IT         | Jim      | 90000  |
| Sales      | Henry    | 80000  |
| IT         | Max      | 90000  |
+------------+----------+--------+
```

The question is to find the highest Salary in each department.

My Python code is like this -

```
import pandas as pd

def department_highest_salary(employee: pd.DataFrame, department: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = employee.merge(department, how = "inner", left_on ="departmentId", right_on = "id")
    df["rank"] = employee.groupby("departmentId")["salary"].rank(method = "dense", ascending=False)
    return( df.query("rank == 1")[["name_y","name_x","salary"]].rename(columns = {"name_y":"Department", "name_x":"Employee", "salary":"Salary"}))
```

It's wrong because `groupby.rank` is returning wrong result -

```
   id_x name_x  salary  departmentId  id_y name_y  rank
0     1    Joe   70000             1     1     IT   2.0
1     2    Jim   90000             1     1     IT   1.0
2     5    Max   90000             1     1     IT   1.0
3     3  Henry   80000             2     2  Sales   2.0
4     4    Sam   60000             2     2  Sales   1.0
```

Why is `Henry` getting rank of 2 shouldn't it be 1? What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only change you need is this:

- Change `employee.groupby` to `df.groupby`.
- If using `pd < 2.2.x` use `how="left"` instead of `how="inner"` to preserve order.

```py
def department_highest_salary(employee: pd.DataFrame, department: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = employee.merge(department, how = "left", left_on ="departmentId", right_on = "id")
    df["rank"] = df.groupby("departmentId")["salary"].rank(method = "dense", ascending=False)
    return( df.query("rank == 1")[["name_y","name_x","salary"]].rename(columns = {"name_y":"Department", "name_x":"Employee", "salary":"Salary"}))

department_highest_salary(employee, department)

  Department Employee  Salary
1         IT      Jim   90000
2      Sales    Henry   80000
4         IT      Max   90000
```

With `how="inner"` (though in your case the choice between methods has no other material effect), the result for `pd < 2.2.x` would be:

```py
  Department Employee  Salary
1         IT      Jim   90000
2         IT      Max   90000
3      Sales    Henry   80000
```

---

**Problem**

You perform the groupby on `employee` rather than the merged `df`. This is a problem because in `pd < 2.2.x` `df.merge(...)` with `how="inner"` does not preserve the order of the left keys.

Compare:

```py
employee[['id', 'name']]

   id   name
0   1    Joe
1   2    Jim
2   3  Henry
3   4    Sam
4   5    Max

df[['id_x', 'name_x']] # the order of `id` values has changed

   id_x name_x
0     1    Joe
1     2    Jim
2     5    Max
3     3  Henry
4     4    Sam
```

I.e., `employee.groupby(...)` does give you the correct *values*, but `df` now has the names in different rows. Since the assignment to `df["rank"]` uses *index* values for mapping, you get mismatches.

This is actually a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/55774): your merge *should* have preserved the order of `employee`, so that your code *should* have worked, even with `employee.groupby`. This has been fixed in `pd 2.2.x` as per the [release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v2.2.0.html#merge-and-dataframe-join-now-consistently-follow-documented-sort-behavior).

Answer (score 1):

**Steps visualization :**

```py
merged = pd.merge(employees, departments, left_on='departmentId', right_on='id', suffixes=('_emp', '_dept'))

###    id_emp name_emp  salary  departmentId  id_dept name_dept
### 0       1      Joe   70000             1        1        IT
### 1       2      Jim   90000             1        1        IT
### 2       5      Max   90000             1        1        IT
### 3       3    Henry   80000             2        2     Sales
### 4       4      Sam   60000             2        2     Sales

merged['max_salary'] = merged.groupby('departmentId')['salary'].transform('max')

###    id_emp name_emp  salary  departmentId  id_dept name_dept  max_salary
### 0       1      Joe   70000             1        1        IT       90000
### 1       2      Jim   90000             1        1        IT       90000
### 2       5      Max   90000             1        1        IT       90000
### 3       3    Henry   80000             2        2     Sales       80000
### 4       4      Sam   60000             2        2     Sales       80000

high_rev = merged[merged['salary'].eq(merged['max_salary'])]

###    id_emp name_emp  salary  departmentId  id_dept name_dept  max_salary
### 1       2      Jim   90000             1        1        IT       90000
### 2       5      Max   90000             1        1        IT       90000
### 3       3    Henry   80000             2        2     Sales       80000

r = high_rev[['name_dept', 'name_emp', 'salary']].drop_duplicates().rename(
    columns={'name_dept': 'Department', 'name_emp': 'Employee', 'salary': 'Salary'}
)

print(r)
```

**Displays :**

```
  Department Employee  Salary
1         IT      Jim   90000
2         IT      Max   90000
3      Sales    Henry   80000
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using `transform` function. You can put the max value of each group at each row, then compare the values of `salary` column will transformed `salary` column. Here is an example based on your table :

```
employee.groupby('departmentId')['salary'].transform(max)
```

Which gives the following output :

```
0    90000
1    90000
2    80000
3    80000
4    90000
Name: salary, dtype: int64
```

You can use it to find max values for each group like this :

```
employee[employee.groupby('departmentId')['salary'].transform(max) == employee['salary']]
```

The result will be :

```
   id   name  salary  departmentId
1   2    Jim   90000             1
2   3  Henry   80000             2
4   5    Max   90000             1
```

Which now can be merged with `department` DataFrame.

```
selected = employee[employee.groupby('departmentId')['salary'].transform(max) == employee['salary']]
result = selected.merge(department,how='inner',left_on ="departmentId", right_on = "id")
```

Which gives you your desired output.

```
   id_x name_x  salary  departmentId  id_y name_y
0     2    Jim   90000             1     1     IT
1     5    Max   90000             1     1     IT
2     3  Henry   80000             2     2  Sales
```

And then you can select the desired columns from this result.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the column and use:

```
out = employee[employee.groupby(employee['departmentId']
                       .map(department.set_index('id')['name'])['salary']
                       .rank('dense', ascending=False).eq(1)
              ]
```

Output:

```
   id   name  salary  departmentId
1   2    Jim   90000             1
2   3  Henry   80000             2
4   5    Max   90000             1
```

Or, if you also want the name of the department:

```
out = (employee
       .merge(department.rename(columns={'id': 'departmentId', 'name': 'Department'}),
              on='departmentId')
       .loc[lambda d: d.groupby('Department')['salary'].rank('dense', ascending=False).eq(1)]  
)
```

Output:

```
   id   name  salary  departmentId Department
1   2    Jim   90000             1         IT
2   5    Max   90000             1         IT
3   3  Henry   80000             2      Sales
```